# Redux Saga seems to block execution even though the saga is started with `spawn`

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I'm using the following setup in my React Native app:

1. The GUI uses `connect` from `react-redux` to fire an action, let's say of type `MY_ACTION`. The action creator is a function which sits on the GUI's props (`connect` puts it there). So, the GUI calls `this.props.sendMyAction()` to dispatch.
2. In my root saga, I have the following dispatcher, which listens for `MY_ACTION` and invokes a background process every time a `MY_ACTION` is dispatched:

```
    function* myActionWatcher() {
        yield takeEvery(MY_ACTION, function*() {
            yield spawn(backgroundSaga);
        });
    }
```

This seems to work. However, the JS thread seems to return to the GUI only when the background saga has completed:

```
this.props.sendMyAction();
console.info('Sent action!');              // <---- only called after backgroundSaga finishes
```

This seems strange, given that `spawn` is exactly the kind of forking mechanism that forks the saga in an asynchronous way, i.e. such that the parent saga does not have to wait until it's finished.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is the same thing we're noticing in your app - sagas of redux-saga overwhelm the main JS thread where even `setInterval()` calls are delayed or not executed at all. And we do have a lot of sagas - but still.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does backgroundSaga do? If it starts off with a synchronous block of code, that code will have to finish executing before control can return back to the parent saga, or to redux, or to your component.

When you call `yield spawn(backgroundSaga)`, you create a detached saga **and begin running that saga**. The saga will run until it `yields` something asynchronous (usually a promise). The fact that the child saga is detached means it's possible for the parent saga to finish even if the child saga hasn't, but the parent still needs to wait for the child to `yield`. Only once the child saga yields does control return back to the parent saga, and then back to redux, and then back to your react component.

For example, suppose i have the following:

```
function* myActionWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery(MY_ACTION, function*() {
    console.log('PARENT: about to spawn');
    yield spawn(backgroundSaga);
    console.log('PARENT: after spawn');
  });
}


function* backgroundSaga() {
  console.log('CHILD: starting saga');
  const state = yield select();
  console.log('CHILD: after select');
  yield Promise.resolve();
  console.log('CHILD: after resolve');
}
```

The order of logs for this will be:

- 'PARENT: about to spawn'
- 'CHILD: starting saga'
- 'CHILD: after select'
- 'PARENT: after spawn'
- 'Sent action!' <-- from your component
- 'CHILD: after resolve'

In other words, the child starts running immediately, and anything synchronous it does (including synchronous yields to redux-saga for information) run to completion. Then once it reaches something asynchronous control returns to the parent, and the child will resume later.

Comment: Thanks, that's about what I expected. However, my saga does have asynchronous yields (like AJAX queries), but the GUI is blocked until the saga completes. Gonna have to find the problem elsewhere. If we used fork instead of spawn, the log 'PARENT: after spawn' would be at the end, right?

Comment: `If we used fork instead of spawn, the log 'PARENT: after spawn' would be at the end, right?` Correct